# Downloaded XML is unorganized

Tags: xml, json, vb.net

When I send the below request through Chrome or Explorer, I receive a neat XML from the server and everything is OK.

http://et.water.ca.gov/api/data?appKey=e5eef4c3-7d8b-48f9-8152-9cad1dbe85c4&targets=15&startDate=2013-10-1&endDate=2013-10-3&dataItems=hly-air-tmp

here is the first line of the XML:

```
<et-xml xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<data><provider name="cimis" type="station" owner="water.ca.gov">
<record date="2013-10-01" julian="274" hour="0100" station="15" standard="english" zip-code="93246, 93245, 93234, 93202, 93266" scope="hourly">
  <hly-air-tmp qc=" " unit="(F)">63.2</hly-air-tmp>
</record>
<record date="2013-10-01" julian="274" hour="0200" station="15" standard="english" zip-code="93246, 93245, 93234, 93202, 93266" scope="hourly">
  <hly-air-tmp qc=" " unit="(F)">63.8</hly-air-tmp>
</record>
<record date="2013-10-01" julian="274" hour="0300" station="15" standard="english" zip-code="93246, 93245, 93234, 93202, 93266" scope="hourly">
  <hly-air-tmp qc=" " unit="(F)">64.1</hly-air-tmp>
</record>
<record date="2013-10-01" julian="274" hour="0400" station="15" standard="english" zip-code="93246, 93245, 93234, 93202, 93266" scope="hourly">
  <hly-air-tmp qc=" " unit="(F)">62.7</hly-air-tmp>
</record>
<record date="2013-10-01" julian="274" hour="050
```

Because of some reasons I need to do this procedure using my VB.Net application. I tried to download the XML file using this code:

```
Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()

myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://et.water.ca.gov/api/data?appKey=e5eef4c3-7d8b-48f9-8152-9cad1dbe85c4&targets=15&startDate=2013-10-1&endDate=2013-10-3&dataItems=hly-air-tmp", fileName)
```

It does download the file. The downloaded file still contains the data I expect but the format of the file is changed and browsers can not load it as an XML file.

I send you few first lines of the downloaded file:

> {"Data":{"Providers":[{"Name":"cimis","Type":"station","Owner":"water.ca.gov","Records":[{"Date":"2013-10-01","Julian":"274","Hour":"0100","Station":"15","Standard":"english","ZipCodes":"93246,
>   93245, 93234, 93202,
>   93266","Scope":"hourly","HlyAirTmp":{"Value":"63.2","Qc":"
>   ","Unit":"(F)"}},{"Date":"2013-10-01","Julian":"274","Hour":"0200","Station":"15","Standard":"english","ZipCodes":"93246,
>   93245, 93234, 93202,
>   93266","Scope":"hourly","HlyAirTmp":{"Value":"63.8","Qc":"
>   ","Unit":"(F)"}},{"Date":"2013-10-01","Julian":"274","Hour":"0300","Station":"15","Standard":"english","ZipCodes":"93246,
>   93245, 93234, 93202,
>   93266","Scope":"hourly","HlyAirTmp":{"Value":"64.1","Qc":"
>   ","Unit":"(F)"}},{"Date":"2013-10-01","Julian":"274","Hour":"0400","Station":"15","Standard":"english","ZipCodes":"93246,
>   93245, 93234, 93202,
>   93266","Scope":"hourly","HlyAirTmp":{"Value":"62.7","Qc":"
>   ","Unit":"(F)"}},{"Date":"2013-10-01","Julian":"274","Hour":"0500","Station":"15","Standard":"english","ZipCodes":"93246,
>   93245, 93234, 93202, 9

I use the following code, which works find to parse the XML, to parse the new file:

```
Dim reader As XmlTextReader
reader = New XmlTextReader("C:\Users\lenovo.pc\Desktop\CIMIS\bin\Debug\ms-banner.xml")
reader.ReadToFollowing("hly-air-tmp")
```

but it returns the following error:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

Is there a way that I can download the well-formatted file? If not, how can I convert the downloaded file to a well-formatted XML (it contains all the data I need).

Comment: You need to set an `Accept` header to say that you want to receive `application/xml` rather than (by the look of things), `application/json`. Reading [`WebClient.Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers(v=vs.110).aspx) indicates that you may have to switch to using the `HttpWebRequest` class to be able to set the `Accept` header.

Comment: That worked!
Now I am getting XML from server.

Here is what I did, in the case of anyone else wants to know:

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://et.water.ca.gov/api/data?appKey=e5eef4c3-7d8b-48f9-8152-9cad1dbe85c4&targets=15&startDate=2013-10-1&endDate=2013-10-1&dataItems=hly-air-tmp"), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Accept = "application/xml"
        Dim myHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data in that file is in JSON format not in XML format.